How do I solve the puzzle behind the groundkeeper's house in Hogwarts Legacy?
Behind the groundkeeper's house (Hagrid's Hut), there's some kind of cave puzzle:

It consists of three pieces.
A cube and a sign on the ground:

And a hole in the ground:

I've tried to put the cube on the sign, but nothing happens:

I've also tried to Accio the cube into the hole in the ground, but the cube instantly disappears and spawns back to its original location as soon as it touches the hole in the ground.
I'm not sure how to progress on this puzzle. How can I solve it?

That's a Spell cube!
Some Treasure Vault puzzles have platforms in front of the vault. To solve the puzzle you need to bring the spell cube to the platform (as you already did).
The part you are missing is that you need to use the spell indicated on the cube to activate the platform. Aim at the cube and use, in this case, Incendio and you will get access to the Treasure Vault.
Note:
There are similar puzzles requesting Levioso or Glacius.
Source Game8.
